# How to change the standard navigation menu color when using genesis

Tags: css, genesis-theme-framework

I need to change the font color for a wordpress menu. I'm currently using genesis as my parent theme & putting all of the css changes for it in a child theme. I would like to change the font color of my primary navigation menu, where do I  put these changes in wordpress? In the child theme style.css or at Appearance > Menus ?

Comment: I've edited this question to make it fit in with the requirements better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to change the background color?

If so, use `background-color: #0066CC` instead of `color: #0066CC`

Comment: Have you tried this:

.menu-primary-container .menu li a